Rename an image file name before uploading to database
I'm building an app in SwiftUI and right now I have it so users can select a photo from their gallery to upload. When they do, I save it locally and store a URL variable for fetching it from it's file path location. I use this URL to load the image in the view to show the user what image they selected.
Now after the user finishes, I want to call an API to upload the image to AWS. However, with how things are set up right now in the project I'm working in, I need to rename the file to a specific name before uploading it to the database.
Now I know before uploading, I'm going to have to convert the image to its data by doing something like:
let uiImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filepath)
let data = uiImage.pngData()

And then use the data to send to AWS. While I haven't tested this yet, I am required to use a presigned URL to upload the image and so will likely do so by setting up a PUT request such as this:
let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
request.httpMethod = "PUT"
request.httpBody = data
request.setValue("image/png", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

But my question is what exactly is this Data object? How can I rename it to match the format I need the image file name to be so then when I upload to the database, it will be saved there with the correct name?

(NS)Data is the high level object/struct of hex/raw data. In your case, it's the raw data of the UIImage, meaning it's "0x 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A ..."

Regarding your upload renaming it depends on your API parameters: What does it accepts, how do you send parameters, etc.

Generally sending image  or video datas to Server as Multipart data and Alamofire does this like thorough. Or you can do it with URLSession.
URLSession: https://orjpap.github.io/swift/http/ios/urlsession/2021/04/26/Multipart-Form-Requests.html
Alamofire: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2942
